# How can I convert a lambda-expression between different (but compatible) models?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

(based on an email conversation, now recorded for information sharing) I have two models used at different layers:

```
public class TestDTO {
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
//...
public class Test {
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

and a lambda in terms of my DTO layer:

```
Expression<Func<TestDTO, bool>> fc1 =
   (TestDTO c1) => c1.CustomerID <= 100 && c1.CustomerID >= 10;
```

How can I convert that lambda (in the general case) to talking about the other model:

```
Expression<Func<Test, bool>> fc2 = {insert magic here, based on fc1}
```

(obviously, we're after the same test-condition, but using the `Test` type)

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To do that, you'll have to rebuild the expression-tree completely; the parameters will need re-mapping, and all member-access that is now talking to different types will need to be reapplied. Fortunately, a lot of this is made easier by the `ExpressionVisitor` class; for example (doing it all in the general case, not just the `Func<T,bool>` predicate usage):

```
class TypeConversionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> parameterMap;

    public TypeConversionVisitor(
        Dictionary<Expression, Expression> parameterMap)
    {
        this.parameterMap = parameterMap;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // re-map the parameter
        Expression found;
        if(!parameterMap.TryGetValue(node, out found))
            found = base.VisitParameter(node);
        return found;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        // re-perform any member-binding
        var expr = Visit(node.Expression);
        if (expr.Type != node.Type)
        {
            MemberInfo newMember = expr.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name)
                                       .Single();
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expr, newMember);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Here, we pass in a dictionary of parameters to re-map, applying that in `VisitParameter`. We also, in `VisitMember`, check to see if we've switched type (which can happen if `Visit` involves a `ParameterExpression` or another `MemberExpression`, at any point): if we have, we'll try and find another member of the same name.

Next, we need a general purpose lambda-conversion rewriter method:

```
// allows extension to other signatures later...
private static Expression<TTo> ConvertImpl<TFrom, TTo>(Expression<TFrom> from)
    where TFrom : class
    where TTo : class
{
    // figure out which types are different in the function-signature
    var fromTypes = from.Type.GetGenericArguments();
    var toTypes = typeof(TTo).GetGenericArguments();
    if (fromTypes.Length != toTypes.Length)
        throw new NotSupportedException(
            "Incompatible lambda function-type signatures");
    Dictionary<Type, Type> typeMap = new Dictionary<Type,Type>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fromTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (fromTypes[i] != toTypes[i])
            typeMap[fromTypes[i]] = toTypes[i];
    }

    // re-map all parameters that involve different types
    Dictionary<Expression, Expression> parameterMap
        = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();
    ParameterExpression[] newParams =
        new ParameterExpression[from.Parameters.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < newParams.Length; i++)
    {
        Type newType;
        if(typeMap.TryGetValue(from.Parameters[i].Type, out newType))
        {
            parameterMap[from.Parameters[i]] = newParams[i] =
                Expression.Parameter(newType, from.Parameters[i].Name);
        }
        else
        {
            newParams[i] = from.Parameters[i];
        }
    }

    // rebuild the lambda
    var body = new TypeConversionVisitor(parameterMap).Visit(from.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<TTo>(body, newParams);
}
```

This takes an arbitrary `Expression<TFrom>`, and a `TTo`, converting it to an `Expression<TTo>`, by:

- finding which types are different between `TFrom` / `TTo`
- using that to re-map the parameters
- using the expression-visitor we just created
- and finally constructing a new lambda expression for the desired signature

Then, putting it all together and exposing our extension method:

```
public static class Helpers {
    public static Expression<Func<TTo, bool>> Convert<TFrom, TTo>(
        this Expression<Func<TFrom, bool>> from)
    {
        return ConvertImpl<Func<TFrom, bool>, Func<TTo, bool>>(from);
    }

    // insert from above: ConvertImpl
    // insert from above: TypeConversionVisitor
}
```

et voila; a general-purpose lambda conversion routine, with a specific implementation of:

```
Expression<Func<Test, bool>> fc2 = fc1.Convert<TestDTO, Test>();
```

Comment: @Kin ta: I forgot to come back to it - there is a delay on accepting self answers

Comment: @MarcGravell i had a problem with code your posted above. Normally your codes works very well but what if destination type doesn't contain a member that exists in source type and also expression. I just want to ignore that expression but i couldn't. Could you help me please?

Comment: @bahadirarslan can't you just check for it and skip it? not clear where the gap is...

Comment: @MarcGravell Error occurs on line  MemberInfo newMember = expr.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single(); Yeah i thought that but i couldn't skip it. returning null, or Expression.Default or anything else doesn't work. Because expr.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name) doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Yay, I had just written a long question looking -exactly- for this. I've deleted it since it's just here. Thanks for this

Answer (score 5):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (no expression tree):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Test, TestDTO>();

...

Func<TestDTO, bool> fc1 =
  (TestDTO c1) => c1.CustomerID <= 100 && c1.CustomerID >= 10;

Func<Test, bool> fc2 =
  (Test t) => fc1(Mapper.Map<Test, TestDTO>(t));
```

Comment: That would work for LINQ-to-Objects, but it won't allow usage with ORMs and other tools based around the `Expression<T>` API. Worth mentioning, though, so a definite +1; but I don't think it helps in the intended case.