# How to convert lambda expressions to and from using boolean types

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I was using the lambda expression conversion class from [How can I convert a lambda-expression between different (but compatible) models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007101/how-can-i-convert-a-lambda-expression-between-different-but-compatible-models) class name "TypeConversionVisitor". It's working well with model queries. When am trying to convert the below it's throwing exceptions.The below is the exception.

```
Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]' and 'System.Boolean'.
  Source=System.Linq.Expressions
  StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetEqualityComparisonOperator(ExpressionType binaryType, String opName, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Update(Expression left, LambdaExpression conversion, Expression right)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at Common.LinqExpressionConverter.ConvertImpl[TFrom,TTo](Expression`1 from) in    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
```

Code :

```
public partial class CompanyHolidaysQuery
{

    public int HolidayID { get; set; }
    public DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public int? ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }
}

public partial class CompanyHolidays
{

    public int HolidayID { get; set; }
    public DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public int? ApplicationTypeID { get; set; }
}
 Expression<Func<CompanyHolidaysQuery, bool>> filter = x => x.ApplicationTypeID == 3 && x.ActiveFlag = true;

 Expression<Func<CompanyHolidays, bool>> switched = filter.Convert<CompanyHolidaysQuery, CompanyHolidays>();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Roopesh

Comment: `x.ActiveFlag = true` is an assignment, not an equality check

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I was doing ==(comparision) only. The below is the correct format.   Expression<Func<CompanyHolidaysQuery, bool>> filter = x => x.ApplicationTypeID == 3 && x.ActiveFlag == true;

 Expression<Func<CompanyHolidays, bool>> switched = filter.Convert<CompanyHolidaysQuery, CompanyHolidays>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationTypeID` is nullable, so check it for a value before comparing:

```
x => x.ApplicationTypeID.HasValue &&  x.ApplicationTypeID.Value == 3 && x.ActiveFlag
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for helping. It's still the same exception. For the applicationTypeID i have hardcoded. The expression is not liking the boolean value "true" for comparison x.ActiveFlag == true

Comment: @RoopeshChadalavada try `x.ApplicationTypeID.Value == 3` instead, so it won't compare with the Nullable, but directly with the value. (and keep the `HasValue` check as suggested here, otherwise this will fail on null values). Also, side note, since `ActiveFlag` is just a boolean, you can just write `&& x.ActiveFlag;`

Comment: Thank you Pac0 and Jonathan. Issue resolved. Your suggestions has made me identify the bug on my side. ActiveFlag in Domain model in nullable and in ViewModel its not nullable. That's where the issued caused. Once again thanks a lot folks.

Comment: @Pac0 thanks, paco. I meant to type that in, but forgot...  :) - edited